# get wrong answer from sql

Tags: sql

first `

```
Select Count(*) From Covids Where AsiDurumu=1
```

I get 12 from first query

Second

```
Select MAX(covidId) From Covids
```

I get 18 from second query

Third Query

```
Select CAST(Count(*) AS FLOAT) / MAX(CovidId) as Asi_Olanlarin_Covid_Orani From Covids Where AsiDurumu=1
```

when i wrote this query i got 0.705858.. but i must get 0.66. why i didn't get

Comment: What does `Select MAX(covidId) From Covids WHERE AsiDurumu=1` return?

Comment: return 17. i get 0.7058 because of 17

Comment: So you want to divide the count of AsiDurumu=1 rows, with the table max covidId value? Does it make any sense?

Comment: yes i want to show rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` *expression* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
Select sum(case when AsiDurumu = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end ) / MAX(CovidId) as Asi_Olanlarin_Covid_Orani
From Covids
```

Comment: is there possible this query write linq version ?

Comment: I don't know linq. Ask a separate question.